# How to properly alter the value of an array element in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

This probably counts as very easy stuff, but since I'm only about 5 weeks into my Comp Sci course, please excuse any ignorance on my part.

As a part of our grade this year, we have to implement a 'Spread-and-Die' game. The interface for this game is a 12 by 12 ASCII layout in the command line.

The code I have made to work out the problem, not my actual code due to a ridiculous length, I have here:

```
class PrintTest
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        final char[] array = {'#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#'};


        char[] array1 = array;
        char[] array2 = array;
        char[] array3 = array;

        array2[6] = 'P';

        System.out.println("\n");

        System.out.print (array1[0]);
        System.out.print (array1[1]);
        System.out.print (array1[2]);
        System.out.print (array1[3]);
        System.out.print (array1[4]);
        System.out.print (array1[5]);
        System.out.print (array1[6]);
        System.out.print (array1[7]);
        System.out.print (array1[8]);
        System.out.print (array1[9]);
        System.out.print (array1[10]);
        System.out.print (array1[11]);

        System.out.print("\n");

        System.out.print (array2[0]);
        System.out.print (array2[1]);
        System.out.print (array2[2]);
        System.out.print (array2[3]);
        System.out.print (array2[4]);
        System.out.print (array2[5]);
        System.out.print (array2[6]);
        System.out.print (array2[7]);
        System.out.print (array2[8]);
        System.out.print (array2[9]);
        System.out.print (array2[10]);
        System.out.print (array2[11]);

        System.out.print("\n");

        System.out.print (array3[0]);
        System.out.print (array3[1]);
        System.out.print (array3[2]);
        System.out.print (array3[3]);
        System.out.print (array3[4]);
        System.out.print (array3[5]);
        System.out.print (array3[6]);
        System.out.print (array3[7]);
        System.out.print (array3[8]);
        System.out.print (array3[9]);
        System.out.print (array3[10]);
        System.out.print (array3[11]);

        System.out.print("\n");
    }
}
```

I also, as you can evidently see, have not been able to find out how to print whole arrays, so any hints there would also be useful, given the ugliness of my solution.

Anyway, when that code is complied/run, I get this:

```
######P#####
######P#####
######P#####
```

Given my admittedly-limited understanding of Java and programming in general, only the second line should have a 'P' in it. For some reason, the statement changing element 6 of array2 is also doing the same for the other two arrays.

Help would be muchly appreciated.

Comment: Probably duplication of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12772443/how-to-change-value-of-arraylist-element-in-java

Answer (score 2):

Because primitive arrays are like objects, they hold a reference. So when assigning `array2[6] = 'P'`, it's like saying `array[6] = 'P'` and hence `array1[6] = 'P'` and `array3[6] = 'P'`.

To avoid that, you can call the method `clone()`, while creating your arrays.

```
char[] array1 = array.clone();
char[] array2 = array.clone();
char[] array3 = array.clone();
```

If you want to copy specify elements for you array, you can use [`Arrays.copyOfRange`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange%28char%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29) :

```
char[] array1 = Arrays.copyOfRange(array, 0, array.length);
                                     ^    ^       ^
                                     |    |       |

                                     |    |    indice to

                                     | indice from

                                     |
                            array to be copied
```

Also to print your arrays, you can use a for loop.

```
for(int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++)
     System.out.print(array1[i]);

System.out.println();
```

Answer (score 1):

Since all your array are pointing to same reference you are getting same values printed

you can create a function to print array, to avoid redundant code

```
class PrintTest
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        final char[] array = {'#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#'};
        char[] array1 = array;
        char[] array2 = array;
        char[] array3 = array;
        array2[6] = 'P';
        printArr(array1);
        printArr(array2);
        printArr(array3);

    }

    public static void printArr(char[] array){
        for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
            System.out.print(array[i]);         
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Instead of assigning array reference , try creating new array as suggested by other answers

Answer (score 0):

This is because you've only created one array, and referred to that exact same array from 3 variables.

You need to create 3 separate arrays, like this:

```
char[] array1 = {'#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#'};
char[] array2 = {'#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#'};
char[] array3 = {'#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#'};
```