# How to change value of ArrayList element in java (when indexOf doesnt work)!

Tags: java, parsing, arraylist, indexof

I've many question like this before, but every solution I've found involves the usage of indexOf. Just like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12772443/how-to-change-value-of-arraylist-element-in-java).

Well, I'm implementing a recursive descent parser, and after execution each production I've to print the production, something like "A = B 'token' (value of token) C". The problem arises when productions have many other productions and tokens, if I print it in the begining of the production I don't have the value of every token, if I print it in the end the final list of productions will be in an incorrect order.

So I'm doing something like this:

```
String s="";
productions.add(s);
A();
getToken();
B();
s=("A 'token' B");
```

You can see that in the method A() I might have something like that too, so I will be addind many s="" to the list, thus **indexOf** wont work. Currently I'm doing this:

```
String s="";
s+= productions.size();
productions.add(s);
A();
getToken();
B();
s=("A 'token' B");
```

But I don't find this solution anyhow elegant. There is a better way to do that?

Here is an example of what I'm trying to do, note that it won't work because you need a lexical analyser that implements the *nextToken* method

```
public class parser {
    ArrayList<String> productions = new ArrayList<>();
    void S(){
        //S = A '*' B
        String s="";
        productions.add(s);
        A();
        nextToken();
        B();
        s="S = A '*' B"
        printProductions();
    }

    void A(){
        //A = 'ctn' | B
        String s="";
        productions.add(s);
        if(!currentTk=ctn){
            s="A = B
            B();
        }else{
            s="A = 'ctn'
        }
    }

    void B(){
        //B = 'ctn' '+' 'ctn'
        String s="";
        productions.add(s);
        if(currentTk=ctn){
            nextToken();
            if(currentTk=ctn){
                if(currentTk=ctn){
                    nextToken();
                    s= "'ctn' '+' 'ctn'"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's very unclear to me what you're trying to achieve - particularly as you're just assigning a literal string at the end, after calling the unknown `A()`, `B()` and `getToken()` methods, ignoring any results. It would be *much* easier to help you if you'd post a [mcve].

Comment: Hey, the objective here is to write out the syntax tree, for that I need to print the productions (A, B,...) in the order they are accessed.

Comment: Nope, I'm afraid that doesn't help to clarify your question for me. I still recommend posting a [mcve].